# SQL SERVER get datetime from a custom formatted string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime-format

I have a table that contains some DateTime values stored as text, and I want to loop through them and get the DateTime object for each one.

Here are some examples of the data that I need to convert it.

- 26 Tuesday November 2019 - 09:00 AM
- 25 Monday November 2019 - 11:20 AM
- 06 Friday December 2019 - 10:00 AM
- 22 Sunday December 2019 - 01:05 PM
- 22 Sunday December 2019 - 04:00 PM
- 22 Sunday December 2019 - 02:30 PM
- 23 Monday December 2019 - 11:00 AM

I tried to use the SQL built-in functions (e.g. cast, convert,...) but didn't work.

Comment: SQL Server version?

Comment: Hopefully the reason you're doing to task is so that you fix your design and change the column from a `varchar` to a date and time data type.

Comment: @gotqn SQL 2018

Comment: @Larnu, exactly, this is what I'll do :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the name of the weekday and the hyphen and it should work:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,datefromparts(2020,1,dow.dow)) as WeekDay
FROM (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7) ) dow(dow)
)

SELECT TRY_CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.dateInTxt,'-',''),cte.WeekDay,'') as datetime),t.dateInTxt
FROM mytable t
JOIN cte
ON t.dateInTxt LIKE '%'+cte.WeekDay +'%'
```